# BASH script help for process restart

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

```
#!/bin/bash

check=`monStatus.sh -p appName:Tomcat |head -2 |tail -1 | nawk '{print $2}'`

if [ "$check" != "offline" ]; then
  #echo "Tomcat still running"
  sleep 90
else
  #echo "Restarting Tomcat"
  RestartTomcat.sh
fi
```

Here is the shell snippet.  My issue is this.  I need the first then to be like `sleep 90` AND then run through the if/then/else statement again basically until it is completes out on the else which will then restart Tomcat once it doesn't say running.  I can't wrap my brain around how to loop it.

Comment: Do you want it to continue looping if you've had to run RestartTomcat.sh?

Comment: No, after it runs the restart it should end.

Comment: Hi, @WesNeal, I've updated my answer, please read the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to repeat the scrip endlessly, you can use a [nested](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html) `while` loop:

```
while true; do
    # Do something, for example output the current date and time:
    printf '%(%c)T\r' -1 
done
```

- In your example code, you are using the old style for subshell output wrapping. As [@ThomasWard](https://askubuntu.com/users/10616/thomas-ward) says: "most Bash guides don't recommend the use of backticks, and instead suggest to wrap your commands within `$( )`, i.e. `$(monStatus.sh -p appName:Tomcat | head -2 | tail -1 | nawk '{print $2}')`. This is actually the more recommended way to do subshell output capture as a variable or as substitution nowadays."

  As [@dessert](https://askubuntu.com/users/507051/dessert) says, "note there's actually a difference between the backticks and the `$(…)` syntax: When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by `$`, `` ` ``, or `\`. – compare the outputs of `echo $(echo \\ )` and `` echo `echo \\ ` ``!"
- In addition, you can simplify few more things:

  Use `nawk 'FNR==2{print $2}'` instead of `head -2 | tail -1 | nawk '{print $2}'`.

  Use Bash builtin test `[` (see `man test` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash) answer), the ['and' list operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html) `&&`, and positive (`==`, `-eq`) instead of negative (`!=`, `-ne`) condition.

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  while true; do
      sleep 90
      [[ $(monStatus.sh -p appName:Tomcat | nawk 'FNR==2{print $2}') == 'offline' ]] && RestartTomcat.sh
  done
  ```

But, according to the comment *"after it runs the restart it should end"*, the correct suggestion is to use `while` with a condition:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ $(monStatus.sh -p appName:Tomcat | nawk 'FNR==2{print $2}') -ne offline ]]
do 
    sleep 90
done
RestartTomcat.sh
```

Or if you want to use a positive condition, the `until` loop can be implemented in the same way:

```
#!/bin/bash
until [[ $(...) -eq offline ]]; do sleep 90; done; RestartTomcat.sh
```